# Miniaturas de imagens no Editor da Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui

Estou com dificuldades no componente "Editor" da Kendo... Ao carregar as imagens ele tem um recurso que simula uma galeria, ou até mesmo a própria pasta no Windows... nessa tela eu consigo (ou pelo menos deveria) visualizar as imagens.

O problema ocorre quando eu tento configurar onde ficam essas imagens... Segundo o [exemplo da Kendo](http://dojo.telerik.com/umuYO) é só colocar a pasta na propriedade path... o problema é que ele sempre coloca uma barra antes da URL, então não sei se ele já vem em algum lugar definido...

[image: No exemplo da kendo, clique na imagem]

[image: Depois de um duplo clique no campo do caminho da imagem]

Alguém sabe como faço pra direcionar pra pasta certa?

Comment: Você possui no seu projeto a pasta imagebrowser ? E a pasta content um na pasta raiz com a pasta images dentro?

Comment: Talvez essa seja um problema de entendimento sobre urls relativas. Dê uma olhada nessa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2315/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-urls-completos-ou-relativos-nos-conte%C3%BAdos-da-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Não, eu não tenho uma pasta imagebrowser... o que eu tenho de pastas para imagens é Raiz > Source > Imagens