# Como importar JavaScript externo e colocar máscaras nos inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masked-input-plugin

Olá, tudo bem?

Vi alguns tutoriais na internet para colocar máscaras em input no HTML, e como sou novo em JavaScript importei a biblioteca externa como mostrado abaixo, mas devo ter importado errado ou usado a função de forma incorreta, pois a máscara não está sendo aplicada.

Segue o código:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    [...]

    jQuery(function($){
        $("#inputTelefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    });
</script>

[...]

<input type="text" name="contato" id="inputTelefone" class="form-control">
```

Obs.: Estou utilizando o plugin Masked Input Plugin for jQuery, cujo readme está disponível em https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/blob/master/README.md

Baixei o arquivo `jquery.maskedinput.js` da página do plugin, coloquei na mesma pasta que o arquivo HTML e funcionou.

Comment: Os arquivos jquery.js e jquery.maskedinput.js estão na mesma pasta que o arquivo html?

Comment: Não... Vou tentar baixar os arquivos e colocar na mesma pasta. Então venho aqui contar se deu certo. Obrigado, Wictor!

Comment: No console do chrome ou firefox acusa algum erro?

Comment: Como você mesmo já editou na pergunta, o problema era na localização do seu arquivo. Recomendo a leitura da seguinte pergunta para você se contextualizar com caminhos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2315/diferença-entre-urls-absolutos-e-relativos-nos-conteúdos-da-página

Answer (score -3):

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#inputTelefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    });
 </script>
```

Tenta usar desta forma