# xmlhttp.open, não aceita subpastas

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Estou com um problema. Faço a requisição XMLHttp e funciona tudo direitinho, porém, na hora de abrir o json ele não carrega, pois está dentro de uma pasta, tento da seguinte maneira("GET", "data/dados.json", true), porém, não abre. Se utilizo o arquivo fora da pasta funciona"GET", "dados.json", true).

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de carregar o arquivo na pasta?

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            var poke = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            Element.prototype.appendAfter = function (element) {
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);
            }, false;
            var NewElement = document.createElement('tr');
            NewElement.innerHTML = '<td>'+poke[i].id+'</td><td>'+poke[i].name+'</td><td><img src="'+poke[i].picture+'"/></td>';
            NewElement.appendAfter(document.getElementsByClassName('head-table'));
            NewElement.innerHTML = '<td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Picture</td>';
            NewElement.appendAfter(document.getElementById('ref'));
            for(i=0;i<poke.length;i++){
                var NewElement = document.createElement('tr');
                NewElement.innerHTML = '<td>'+poke[i].id+'</td><td>'+poke[i].name+'</td><td><img src="'+poke[i].picture+'"/></td>';
                NewElement.appendAfter(document.getElementById('ref'));
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/dados.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

Comment: O que aparece no console? Algum erro deve ter. Deve ser esse o problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2315/3635 (caminhos relativos)

Comment: Qual o endereço da página que está a fazer o pedido ?

Comment: Consegui, por algum motivo não estava indo antes, dai hoje quando sentei no meu computador e resolvi tentar novamente sem nenhuma modificação foi. Mas obrigado a todos!!