# Navegação entre pastas

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Boa tarde,

tenho varias pastas

ex: pasta1, pasta2 e pasta3

dentro de cada pasta tem um index.html

preciso criar um botão que quando eu clico em avançar ele pule para a pasta 2 e acesse o index.html e quando eu clicar em avançar de novo ele acesse a pasta 3 e o index.html

O problema e que eu não posso colocar o caminho exato da pasta precisava que ele seguisse uma ordem.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: não basta usar `href="pasta1/index.html"` e assim por diante?

Comment: Amigo como assim **"não posso colocar o caminho exato da pasta"** se vc não pode colocar um `href` com o caminho como quer que o link "adivinhe" para onde tem que ir

Comment: queria que ele percorresse a ordem de pasta que esta na raiz

Comment: Acho que isso vai te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2315/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-urls-absolutos-e-relativos-nos-conte%C3%BAdos-da-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Você precisa receber as informações das pastas que estão no diretório pelo lado do servidor para poder criar os links com o atributo `href` correto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se você estiver com a file aberta mesmo no browser, por exemplo `file:///Users/user/Desktop/Landing/index.html`, não é possível fazer isso, pois você está abrindo uma pasta do seu computador. Você pode baixar o VS Code ou algum editor de texto que tenha um simulador no browser e fazer um `<a href="/index.html" >Link</a>`