# Como adicionar uma imagem no corpo html de um email

Tags: html

Estou tentando fazer um esquema de envio automático utilizando c# .NET, o meu problema esta na hora de adicionar uma imagem no corpo do email, no qual a imagem não aparece.

Este ícone aparece no lugar da imagem que estou tentando incerir: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Html do corpo do email:

```
<div>
    <img src = "../ModelOdyss/Images/image.png">
</div>
```

A imagem que estou tentando incerir esta dentro da pasta "Images" e o html esta dentro da pasta "ControllerOdyss".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde estou errando ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que colocar o caminho absoluto da imagem. Tipo:

```
src="http://meusite.com/ModelOdyss/Images/image.png"
```

Onde em `meusite.com` você irá colocar o domínio do seu site.

O cliente de email não vai achar o caminho relativo `../ModelOdyss/Images/image.png` e irá exibir no lugar esse ícone de imagem quebrada.

Dá uma lida [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2315/8063) para entender um pouco sobre caminhos relativo e absoluto.

Comment: Acabei de tentar a alteração e continua não dando certo. Sera se é porque ao invés de "meusite.com" estou usando localhost ?

Comment: Exatamente... o cliente de email irá buscar a imagem na internet, não tem como buscar no seu computador... a não ser que seu servidor local esteja configurado para estar visível na internet..

Comment: E mesmo assim você iria ter que colocar o ip ou um domínio que aponte pro seu servidor. Mas isso é algo meio complicado de fazer. Vc vai trabalhar somente com servidor local, não vai subir pra uma hospedagem?

Comment: Futuramente sim. Contudo gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de anexar esta imagem utilizando localhost.

Comment: Infelizmente não tem como. A imagem deve estar num servidor na internet.