# Página com parâmetro não renderizando CSS

Tags: css, node.js, express.js

Olá, estou com um problema na renderização da minha página. Quando eu faço um route com parâmetro na URL o css do bootstrap simplesmente não renderiza, no entanto, caso eu faça um route que não possua nenhum parâmetro na url o css é carregado normalmente.

```
app.get( '/encontrista/:idEncontrista', isLoggedIn, function( req, res )
{
    res.render( 'signup.ejs', { message: req.flash( 'message' ) } );
} );
```

[image: Ao lado esquerdo a página problemática e ao lado direito a mesma página com exceção do parâmetro na url.]

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Diferença entre URLs absolutos e relativos nos conteúdos da página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2315/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-urls-absolutos-e-relativos-nos-conte%c3%bados-da-p%c3%a1gina)

Comment: Tente colocar o endereço completo antes do caminho atual. Por exemplo: `http://localhost:3000/vendor ...`. A resposta linkada explica mais sobre isso.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver, coloquei relativo ao caminho e funcionou perfeitamente! troquei de `vendor/` p/ `/vendor/`