# Como posso manter as minhas páginas organizadas?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, em alguns arquivos me deparei com uma grande quantidade de codes em `JS` dentro dos meus arquivos de `PHP` e uma grande quantidade de `modals` do bootstrap também.

### Mas qual o problema?

Eu sei que o correto é manter os arquivos de cada linguagem separados um dos outros, mas creio eu, mas por conta de organização. E eu comecei a me sentir incomodado com isso, e resolvi tentar organizar de uma maneira melhor.

No final da minha página HTML, eu usei esses 2 códigos:

```
<!-- Incluindo modals utilizados nessa página -->
<?php include('organizacao_paginas/Modals/painel-admin.php') ?>

<!-- Incluindo scripts e funções utilizadas nessa página -->
<script src="organizacao_paginas/JS/painel-admin.js"></script>
```

Aparentemente o primeiro `include`, está funcionando normalmente, consigo abrir os modals e etc.

Porém o `<script src=...>` já não está, todas as funções dessa página, não funcionam, já tentei colocar o mesmo dentro do `<head></head>` e também utilizar o próprio `include`, mas sem sucesso.

**Como posso estar incluindo esse arquivo `JS` para que funcione normalmente?**

> Me desculpem se eu falei algo incoerente, podem me corrigir e obrigado a todos desde já.

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema como caminho relativo do seu `src`.

Comment: Já tentou colocar um ./ antes do caminho no script?

Comment: Relacionado: [Diferença entre URLs absolutos e relativos nos conteúdos da página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2315/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-urls-absolutos-e-relativos-nos-conte%C3%BAdos-da-p%C3%A1gina)

Comment: Já sim, sem sucesso.

Comment: Consegue enviar uma print com a estrutura das pastas/arquivos?

Comment: @user210741 você precisaria mostrar a estrutura de diretório que estão esse(s) arquivo(s). Eles rodam a partir de alguma subpasta? Se sim, pode ser o problema, mas fica difícil fazer sem saber mais detalhes.

Comment: @LuizFelipe tentei usar os 3, mas sem sucesso...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters estou estranhando, pois os 2 arquivos que estou tentando incluir, está na mesma pasta, e apenas 1 está funcionando. [Veja as pastas](https://prnt.sc/vet8ac)

Comment: Uma solução interessante também é usar um padrão de arquitetura para manter o código mais limpo, você pode optar por exemplo pelo MVC, é um ótima solução!

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada, obrigado! @user210680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvi o meu problema dessa maneira:** Apertei (CTRL + U), e desci para ver se a página estava sendo incluída ou não, e percebi que não estava.

Por algum motivo com `<script src=""...>` não funcionou, mas funcionou utilizando `include` dessa maneira:

```
<script>
<?php include('organizacao_paginas/js/painel-admin.js'); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: É, mas nesse caso tem que notar que você não está utilizando o script como recurso **externo**, mas sim da própria página. Dependendo do caso, pode não fazer diferença, mas há de se saber que são coisas diferentes. Uma outra forma de ver isso é que agora você está delegando ao PHP a responsabilidade de "importar" uma coisa que antes era papel do _browser_ (`<script src="..."></script>`).

Comment: Sim, utilizei apenas para ficar mais organizado "em minha visão", mas sei que internamente o code está ali rsrs, eu realmente gostaria de utilizar o `<script src="..."></script>`, porém, não estava funcionando :(